# Spine Leaf L3 TOR DMZ Design for Virtual Environments

Tags: routing, vlan, firewall, network, vmware

[image: Basic DC Design]I have a question regarding DMZ design in our DC. Let me give you some background.

We have

1 rack
2 Spines 
2 leafs L3 TOR connected to each spine
ESXI hosts connected to the leafs
1 Palo ALto Active/Standby connected to the Spines

I want to have my DMZ network and internal VM network shared on the existing ESXI hosts.

So the problem im trying to overcome is at my TOR i will have defined SVI,s for

1 Management 
2 Vmotion 
3 Storage 
4 VXLAN
5 VM 
6 DMZ

How do i logically separate my DMZ VLAN and VM VLAN from communicating with each other if i have L3 TOR (SVI Configured) and ultimately get my VM traffic to route to the F/W for routing back to the DMZ on the same host

Some of my thoughts are to have a separate VRF?? or extend L2 Vlan from F/W down to Leaf switches

Thx

Comment: Why do you connect devices to your spines? In typical spine/leaf designs they would only be used for leaf-interconnects, not for connecting any other devices. A small diagram of your topology might help getting better answers.

Comment: Even if i had leaf switches for my F/W connectivity is does not solve my question. I will try get a diagram up. Thx

Comment: The reason I mentioned it is that your description doesn't fit the spine/leaf model, and that I'm wondering how your network is designed. Typically, you'd assign a VNI for each VLAN and just transport the traffic from one VXLAN VTEP to another one, but spines typically don't have VTEPs.

Comment: That would be a good way to do it.. but im not using any fire-walling in NSX.. there is a requirement that the Palo Alto be the firewall for the DMZ

Comment: So your spines do not have VTEPs for those VLANs? (this is essentially why I made my initial remarks about connecting devices to spines)

Comment: My VTEPs are a VMkernal port on the esxi hosts encapsulating traffic and routing it over L3

Comment: Slightly off topic, but why do you have spine switches at all?  All your hosts are on one leaf or the other, and they're interconnected.   What do the spines do?

Comment: Is that the size of your network? Like Ron, I don't see the point for this complicated setup. Just trunk the VLANs from the core switches to PAs and ESXis and be done with it. Use L3 switching only for the VM subnets (some security zone) and route everything else in the PAs. What you've got isn't really spine-leaf but more collapsed core, but even that's oversized.

Comment: This Leaf/Spine design has one issue (amongst several, probably): as shown,  Leaf1 and Leaf2 are not two leaves, but a single one (read: Leaf1a, Leaf1b), interconnected at Layer 2 by some form of Multichassis Link Aggregation feature (such as  VPC on Nexus as the sketch hints).  With the L2/L3 boundary at the leaf, leaves should not interconnect directly, but a single leaf may of course may be a pair of MLAG/VPC switches.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically your problem is that your leafs are acting as routers and they are needed to reach the firewalls, but they route traffic between those VLANs because SVI's are available.

Personally, I'd say that this is an issue with your topology, and that if you're using VXLAN in a spine/leaf setup, you'd connect your firewalls to leafs, and just let the traffic from various VLANS on your hypervisors reach the firewalls *without* routing in the overlay network. That way you can completely separate traffic for the various VLANs by assigning a unique VNI to each VLAN.

Since you indicated that moving those firewalls to leaf ports was not an option, you could consider adding VTEPs on the spines as well as the leafs. That way you connect your firewalls on layer 2  to your hosts.

I understand that this may not be the solution you're looking for. As you said yourself, you could consider putting each VLAN in its own routing instance (VRFs). I *think* that may work (if all equipment supports it), since you can then add a route to the firewalls in every VRF and use those firewall to route between the VRFs. I'm not 100% sure if it will work though, I'd test it in a lab setup to be sure.